# Plotting Error bar in R

Tags: r, statistics, errorbar

I have the following dataset:

```
            conf    variable        value
1           C1      T1      0.6578166
2           C2      T1      0.6729989
3           C3      T1      0.6629129
4           C4      T1      0.6602419
5           C5      T1      0.6951054
6           C1      T2      0.6764889
7           C2      T2      0.7008580
8           C3      T2      0.6921985
9           C4      T2      0.6868215
10          C5      T2      0.7104877
11          C1      T3      0.6834098
12          C2      T3      0.7120974
13          C3      T3      0.7045760
14          C4      T3      0.6986261
15          C5      T3      0.7180474
16          C1      T4      0.6875082
17          C2      T4      0.7185950
18          C3      T4      0.7122448
19          C4      T4      0.7051376
20          C5      T4      0.7229975
21          C1      T5      0.6902167
22          C2      T5      0.7228775
23          C3      T5      0.7167748
24          C4      T5      0.7093825
25          C5      T5      0.7261777
....
```

I want to plot these data as a line plot with error bars. To do that, I used the `summarySE` function that is defined in this [website](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#line-graphs). I want the plot to be a line plot where the x axis represents the `variable` and the y axis represents the `value` and group by `conf`. The error bar should be presented with each variable considering the values from `T1` to the point of the current variable. For example, the considered values for the error bar in `T6` should be the values from `T1` to `T6`.

Based on that, I called the `summarySE` function as:

```
m2 <- summarySE(m, measurevar = "value", groupvars = c("variable","conf") , na.rm=TRUE)
```

The results that I got are:

```
     variable    conf N  value     sd se ci
1    T1          C1   1  0.6578166 NA NA NA
2    T1          C2   1  0.6729989 NA NA NA
3    T1          C3   1  0.6951054 NA NA NA
4    T1          C4   1  0.6629129 NA NA NA
5    T1          C5   1  0.6602419 NA NA NA
6    T2          C1   1  0.6764889 NA NA NA
......
```

I also tried the following:

```
m2 <- summarySE(m, measurevar = "value", groupvars = c("conf") , na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got the following results:

```
             conf  N     value          sd          se          ci
1              C1 60 0.7038542 0.009609437 0.001240573 0.002482381
2              C2 60 0.7395447 0.012869318 0.001661422 0.003324497
3              C3 60 0.7418830 0.010397609 0.001342326 0.002685987
4              C4 60 0.7365407 0.014438260 0.001863971 0.003729798
5              C5 60 0.7301954 0.014389284 0.001857649 0.003717146
```

But that does not work to plot the error bar with every variable.

To draw the plot:

```
coverage_plot <- ggplot(m2, aes(x=m$variable, y=m$value, group=conf, color=conf)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-ci, ymax=value+ci), width=0.1, position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd) + geom_point(position=pd) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = c(1:60))
```

When I run the code, I also get the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): ymin, ymax, x, y, group, colour
```

Can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. Can you provide a  reproducible example??

Comment: @koundy I am sorry. Do you mean providing a plot?

Comment: Yes try plotting with some inbuilt datasets like iris data and show the plot here.

Comment: your example data only has one observation for each group at each variable, how do you propose to derive the errors without more observations?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `$` in `aes` like this

```
coverage_plot <- ggplot(m2, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=conf, color=conf)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-ci, ymax=value+ci), width=0.1, position=pd) +
      geom_line(position=pd) + geom_point(position=pd) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = c(1:60))
```

Also there is no column called variable in your data. Make sure you are writing correct name